# Independence of three events

Tags: probability, graph-theory, independence

Let $G$ be a graph with three vertices $u,v,w$. Moreover, each vertex has a real-valued label $l(d) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $d$ in $\{u,v,w\}$.

Now let $b(x) = \lfloor \frac{x-u}{\delta} \rfloor$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $u$ is choosen uniform at random from $[0,\delta]$.

Now let $X_{uv}$ and $X_{vw}$ denote two discrete random variables, such that $X_{uv} = 1$ if $b(u) = b(v)$ and $0$ otherwise, likewise for $X_{vu}$. It is easy to so that the probability that two labels get the same value is $\max(0, 1 - (|x-y|/\delta))$.

My question is, if both variables are independent. I do not think so because the values of, e.g., $X_{vw}$ can, in some situations, influence the value of $X_{vu}$ and vice versa. Note that $u$ is the same for all three vertices. Am I right?

Comment: By $b(v)$ etc. do you mean $b(l(v))$? It seems that $b$ is a 1-to-1 function, so you might as well say $l(u) = l(v)$, i.e. $X_{uv} = 1$ if $u$ and $v$ have the same label. Since you haven't said how those labels are chosen, we can't say anything about the probability. But then it seems that the parameters $\delta$ and $u$ are irrelevant; and also that the graph $G$ is irrelevant. Please explain more.